# How can I deploy image to Azure App Service from an ACR which is located in different subscription?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, terraform, azure-appservice

I want to deploy an image to Azure App Service. The image is in the ACR which is in different subscription and App Service is in other subscription. Is there any way to deploy the image.

I will be using terraform to setup the App Service and Azure DevOps Pipeline to deploy new version of images

Answer (score 1):

In case when your ACR is in a different subscription you need to treat this ACR as private docker hub and provide [following app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/10008/using-acr-across-subscriptions-with-web-app-for-co.html):

- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL
- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME
- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD

Of course you need to provide also [`linux_fx_version`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service#linux_fx_version)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can test it. This looks promising